# How to run a service once div element is present

Tags: angular

I have a component that loads a map during `ngAfterViewChecked`.

I have a service that I want to run after the map is fully-loaded in `#map` div element.

Once the map is properly/fully loaded, `#map` now has `canvas` children.

The problem right now is, I don't know what's the PROPER way of initiating a service once the `canvas` elements in the `#map` are present.

**map.component.ts**

1st version:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.map.load();
    console.log(window['something']); // DOESNT WORK
    // this.service.run();
}
```

2nd version:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.map.load().then(res => {
        console.log(window['something']); // DOESNT WORK
        // this.service.run();
    });
}
```

**map.service.ts**

```
public load() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            let node = document.createElement('script');
            node.src = '/Scripts/map-loader.js';
            node.type = 'text/javascript';
            node.async = true;
            node.charset = 'utf-8';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    });
}
```

It's pretty tough since the map loader is an external Javascript.

Really hoping for someone to shed some light.

**EDITED [UPDATED CODE]**

**map.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../../service/service.config';
import { RequestService } from '../../service/service.request';
import { MapRenderService } from '../../service/map-render.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/component/map/map.component.html'
})

export class MapComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(private send: RequestService, private config: ConfigService, private mapRender: MapRenderService) {
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.mapRender.load().then(res => {
            console.log(window['micello']); // ALWAYS PRINTS HERE
        });
    }
}
```

**map-render.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MapRenderService {

    private loader = '/Scripts/map-loader.js';

    public load() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let node = document.createElement('script');
            node.src = '/Scripts/map-loader.js';
            node.type = 'text/javascript';
            node.async = true;
            node.charset = 'utf-8';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

[image]

Comment: why promise and why are you using afterchecked. you can have them as `Observable` which will reduce this overhead

Comment: let me try that one with `Observable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `resolve` call in promise . 
Change service to this.

```ts
public load() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            let node = document.createElement('script');
            node.src = '/Scripts/map-loader.js';
            node.type = 'text/javascript';
            node.async = true;
            node.charset = 'utf-8';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
           resolve();
    });
}
```

And run the 2nd version with `then`

Comment: Hi @Skeptor, thanks for the feedback. Upon updating with `resolve()`, the console is printing infinitely and is causing a browser hang. I'm using the second version of `map.component.ts`

Comment: You are having only console in then and still infinite loop ?

Comment: Added Screenshot.

Comment: That's because of `ngAfterViewChanged` put in `ngOnInit`